# Conductor : Force Callback in onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult, conductor

I am using [Conductor](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor) in place of Fragment which gets attached to activity.

Scenario:

`LocationConductor` which has attached to `MotherActivity`. From `LocationConductor`, I am accessing `GoogleApiClient` which request for `LocationRequest` dialog.

From LocationConductor :

```
LocationSettingsResult.getStatus().startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_LOCATION_SETTINGS);
```

It request `LocationRequestDialog` using `GoogleApiClient` which requires `Activity` Context. The CallBack from the Dialog will be back in `onActivityResult` of `MotherActivity` as `Activity` Context is passed.

Question :

- *I want that callback in to LocationConductor instead of MotherActivity. How can I force callback in conductor or pass conductor context while calling LocationRequest?*

Tried :

- registerForActivityResult(requestCode) : But neither does this help in forcing callback at Conductor.

`registerForActivityResult :  Registers this Controller to handle onActivityResult responses. Calling this method is NOT necessary when calling {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}`

Answer (score 2):

You can just call `Router.onActivityResult()` from within the activity's onActivityResult call to forward it along. If the activity itself calls `startActivityForResult`, there's no way to capture the results automatically. The same would go for fragments.

Comment: Hey, I tried `Router.onActivityResult()` from Activity. But it does not invoke/forward it to `Controller` 's onActivityResult.

Comment: You have to `Controller.registerForActivityResult()` first, as you noted.